# How to search by date in C# using postgreSQL WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql

I am not sure how to word the title but here is what I get. I am pulling all product serial numbers from the database with a date greater than 2014-12-31. The application some what works, I get 4 records returned in my C# application but when I run the sql query in PostgreSQL I get 5 records returned.

Here is my sql statement in C#

```
 NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(
  @"select product_serial_number from master_product 
    where status = 110 and updated_at_time >= :date 
    order by product_serial_number asc;", conn);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("date", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Date).Value = 
    DateTime.Parse("2014-12-31 23:59:59");
```

Not sure how to debug this,any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could start looking at the 5th record returned by the database that is not present in the records returned by code and try to understand what goes on

Comment: This looks like strictly a sql problem. Can you show the records you are getting and what you expect?

Comment: I get the result 4103526, 4103528,4103520, and 4103531 in C# in PostgreSQL I get 4103526, 4103528,4103520,4103531 and 4103519

Comment: I'm really not sure how you think those numbers can help me or anyone.  What I was asking for is the whole record, including the dates, that you are searching on.  I'm sure that you've just done something like `>` on one query and `>=` on another.

Comment: what are the datetime stamps of the 5 records that get returned from PostgreSQL query? Do you specify the time part of the date when you run the query in PostgreSQL? If not, the time part of the date could be 00:00:00 which would then include anything on that date

Comment: Or more likely... you are searching WITH the hour in c# but WITHOUT the hour in postgres.  So its excluding the day.  eg. `2014-12-31` == `2014-12-31 00:00:00`

Comment: Sorry I am using updated_at_time is the date field in table and it is in this format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss I am try to pull all serial number for this year. I just can't figure out the same sql statement yields different results.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, it wasn't my SQL statement it was the way I handles the data reader here the original code

```
 if (dr.Read())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    object serialNumber = dr["product_serial_number"];
                    lbBeltFinalBuild.Items.Add(serialNumber.ToString());

                }

                // Assign totals to variables and display them in a label control
                BeltFinalTotal = lbBeltFinalBuild.Items.Count;
                lblBeltFinalBuild.Text = "Total " + BeltFinalTotal.ToString();


            }
            else
            {
                lbBeltFinalBuild.Items.Add("No Data");
                lblBeltFinalBuild.Text = "Total 0";
            }
```

I changed it to this

```
while (dr.Read())
            {
                object serialNumber = dr["product_serial_number"];
                lbBeltFinalBuild.Items.Add(serialNumber.ToString());
            }

            if (lbBeltFinalBuild.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                lbBeltFinalBuild.Items.Add("No Data");
                lblBeltFinalBuild.Text = "Total 0";
            }
            else
            {
                BeltFinalTotal = lbBeltFinalBuild.Items.Count;
                lblBeltFinalBuild.Text = "Total " + BeltFinalTotal.ToString();
            }
```

and I get the same result when I run the statement in pg admin.